# Need to call different Ruby method depending on what version is installed

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that iterates over `each` line of a text file.

In Ruby 1.8.* using `content.each do |line|` works fine, but in Ruby 1.9.* that does not work, and I need to use `content.each_line do |line|`.

Since this script will be used by several different people, I need to be able to use the right method depending on their version of Ruby.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `IO#each` and `IO#each_line` are aliases of each other in Ruby 1.8, 1.9 and 2.0. What's going wrong?

Comment: @molf, Most likely, _content_ is a string.  Ruby 1.8 had _String#each_; Ruby 1.9 uses _String#each_line_ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global constant `RUBY_VERSION` contains the version of the currently running Ruby. So this script will do what you want:

```
if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9.2"
  # code for 1.8.7
else
  # code for 1.9.2+
end
```

If the inner code of the `each_line` is equal with `1.8.*` and `1.9.*`, the following approach is more DRY:

```
each_selector = RUBY_VERSION < "1.9.2" ? :each : :each_line
content.send(each_selector) do | line|
   # ...
end
```